# Jquery ui autocomplete force user to pick answere

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using JQuery UI autocomplete. Everything works as expected, but when a user clicks next to the results it closes. Now I need a responsive of the user or there stuck on that part of the page.

So now my question, How to force the user to give a input and keep the results until the user clicks on a result?

Here you can see the behavior of jquery ui http://jsfiddle.net/6mz2B/

```
$("#customer-search").autocomplete({
    source: [{
        label: "Tom Smith",
        value: "1234"},
    {
        label: "Tommy Smith",
        value: "12321"}],
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#customer-search").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#selected-customer").val(ui.item.label);
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#customer-search").val(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a strange functionality you're looking for, what's the purpose of this being implemented, so I could you towards an alternative solution.

Comment: The functionality is to pick a hotel location, you can check it out here http://www.triprebel.com/ and than just search (your still seeing the old version the new version is not hiding the complete popup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you could make use of the underlying [`.show()` and `.hide()` functions](http://api.jquery.com/show/) (all they do is change the css `display` property) to make sure that you only ever close the autocomplete menu after a [`select` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select).

```
$(elt).on("autocompleteclose", function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("widget").show();
});
$(elt).on("autocompleteselect", function() {
    $(this).autocomplete("widget").hide();
});
```

Eg. here: http://jsfiddle.net/ua64n/

HOWEVER note that this is strongarming the autocomplete functionality, and there is most likely a better (and less fragile) way to do it. Provide more details, and I'll try to suggest an alternative.